# Cosmos db strongly typed Id

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

It is possible somehow set id as object?

This is sample code

```
    public record MovieId(Guid id);
    public class Movies
    {
        public MovieId MovieId { get; set; }
        public string Movie { get; set; }
        public int Copies { get; set; }

    }
  var client = new CosmosClient(constring);
  var movie = new Movies() { MovieId = new MovieId(Guid.NewGuid()), Copies = 4, Movie = "ff" };
  await continer.Container.CreateItemAsync(movie);
```

Comment: what is the issue, with the existing code?

Comment: "(Message: {"Errors":["The input name '{' is invalid. Ensure to provide a unique non-empty string less than '1024' characters."]}"

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible somehow set id as object?

AFAIK, the answer is no. The `id` property of a document has to be of `string` type.

From this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-document#body):

[image]

Comment: So maybe, can i type converter from object to string before save document? It is possible?

Comment: With proper serialization, it sounds doable though I have not tried it. Can you give it a try and share the result? I would be curious to know the result.

Comment: i found solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It can be done, if you declare `MovieId`like this, you can just think like passing a class object.

```
public record MovieId
{
    Guid _id;
    public MovieId(Guid id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have got this error "The input content is invalid because the required properties - 'id; ' - are missing"

Comment: its working fine for me. try this  `public MovieId(Guid id) => (_id) = (id);` as constructor

Comment: var client = new CosmosClient(constring);
               var result = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("MoviesDB");
                var continer = await result.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync("Movies", "/PatronKey");
                var movie = new Movies() { MovieId = new MovieId(Guid.NewGuid()), Copies = 4, Movie = "ff", PatronKey = "test"};
              await  continer.Container.CreateItemAsync(movie, new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.PartitionKey(movie.PatronKey));

Comment: and model    public record MovieId
    {

        Guid _id;
        public MovieId(Guid id) => (_id) = (id);
    }
    public class Movies
    {
        public MovieId MovieId { get; set; }
        public string Movie { get; set; }
        public int Copies { get; set; }
        public string PatronKey { get; set; }

    }

Comment: Why do you want MovieId as record?why can’t you just declare it as Guid?

Comment: because i want in the future skip the situation where i got method which took 2 ids for example void abc(Guid MovieId, Guid OrderId) and i would like to handle custom type

Comment: It’s working as expected for me, might be cosmosdb not supporting. Using the Guid instead of record will serve you the same purpose. Or use as class or struct

Comment: can u share me a sample and i will try this?

Comment: Just declare like this `public Guid MovieId`  and pass like this `MovieId = Guid.NewGuid()`

Comment: still not working. Can u paste your solution how it works at yours?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i done some research and i found solution of my problem, thanks guys for trying to help

```
  [JsonConverter(typeof(IdConverter))]
    public record BaseId(Guid Value);
    public class IdConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var id = (BaseId)value;
            serializer.Serialize(writer, id.Value);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var guid = serializer.Deserialize<Guid>(reader);
            return new BaseId(guid);
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(BaseId);
        }
    }
```